# Каким образом, MySQL сравнивает строки с числами

Tags: mysql, база-данных

К примеру, у меня есть пара запросов:

```
SELECT '10'    > '-100'    # TRUE
SELECT '10'    > -100      # TRUE 
SELECT '10str' > -99999999 # TRUE
```

Каким образом MySQL выполняет сравнение строк и чисел? Почему в первом запросе, `результат = TRUE`, когда как, строка `-100` длиннее строки `100` ?

Comment: Сравнивается вовсе даже не длина, а коды символов посимвольно. В соответствии с текущим collation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для сравнения данных, они приводятся к одному типу. MySQL приведет число к строке и будет сравнивать строки. А строки уже сравниваются посимвольно. Посмотрите на код 1 и код -